# VM Freezes and Crashes on Reboot

Tags: uefi, qemu

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Windows 11 and Rocky Linux with QEMU 7.0 (qemu-system-aarch64), VM does not restart and freezes. I myself close QEMU with CTRL+C. As a result, it either does not see the HDD or OVMF does not work at all.

Note: With ITS turned on, Windows crashes while booting, but Linux distributions work fine. Also, ITS works with the following warning:

```
warning: ITS KVM: full reset is not supported by the host kernel
```

My parameter:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2G -cpu host -accel kvm -device usb-ehci -device intel-hda  -M virt-6.1,its=off -smp 8 -device ramfb -device usb-kbd  -device usb-mouse -device usb-tablet -drive file=/sdcard/rocky.iso,media=cdrom,if=none,id=drivers -device usb-storage,drive=drivers -device ahci,id=ahci  -accel 3d -drive id=disk,file=/sdcard/w11.raw,if=none -device ide-hd,drive=disk,bus=ahci.0 -chardev socket,id=chrtpm,path=/data/local/tmp/ubuntu/emulated_tpm -tpmdev emulator,id=tpm0,chardev=chrtpm -pflash /sdcard/flash0.img -pflash /sdcard/flash1.img
```

Comment: Did you ensure the WIN11 system thinks it has UEFI, secure boot, and TPMV2 available to it?

Comment: I'm using Redmi Note 10S and I can already install them all. I already used it at 11 but that's not my problem. My VM freezes when I try to reboot. As a result, OVMF, doesn't see my RAW disk at all, or OVMF it doesn't work at all. So it's softbrick or hardbrick.

Comment: You may wish to consider VMware Pro (as I posted in my answer). VMware is more flexible and adaptable to newer operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

> With ITS turned on, Windows crashes while booting,

There is quite a bit of work to install Windows 11 in QEMU because of the significant requirements of Windows 11.

(If you need a Windows 11 VM, consider VMware Professional V16. VMware has a much easier setup for Windows 11).

Please see:

[Install Windows 11 in QEMU](https://www.tecklyfe.com/how-to-create-a-windows-11-virtual-machine-in-qemu/#:%7E:text=The%20main%20requirements%20are%20the,QEMU%20in%20Linux%20and%20Mac.)

> You’ll need to have QEMU 4.0 or higher installed to get TPM 2.0
> emulation. The other hardware minimum requirements for Windows 11
> include 4GB RAM and a 64GB hard drive.
>
> You’ll need to download the Windows 11 ISO and mount it and go through
> the setup process.
>
> Since QEMU is command-based, the steps for this virtualization
> software are different than the others.
>
> First you’ll need to create your virtual machine image and we’ll use a
> 64GB disk size since that’s the minimum requirement for Windows 11:
>
> ENABLE TPM AND SECURE BOOT IN QEMU Now you need to create a temp
> directory for the SWTPM simulator and create the socket in TPM2 mode
> to use with these commands:
>
> mkdir /tmp/emulated_tpm swtpm socket --tpmstate dir=/tmp/emulated_tpm
> --ctrl type=unixio,path=/tmp/emulated_tpm/swtpm-sock --log level=20 --tpm2
>
> Next, you’ll need to start your guest VM with the TPM options:
>
> qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ~/qemu-images/win11.img -boot d -m 4096
> -enable-kvm \   -chardev socket,id=chrtpm,path=/tmp/emulated_tpm/swtpm-sock \   -tpmdev
> emulator,id=tpm0,chardev=chrtpm -device tpm-tis,tpmdev=tpm0